# What is the purpose of rehashing?

Tags: math, key, return-value, hashcode

What is the purpose of rehashing? if I were to explain this concept to a newcomer. How I could rephase this concept so they would understand?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you want to evenly distribute items among bins.  If all of the items were in the same bin, you should redistribute (read: rehash) them *in a different way* or change the number of bins and redistribute them.